# Using One To a mean A Person

Tags: pronouns

Is it plausible to use “one” at the end of a sentence? As in, “one has to have a reasonable trait.” rewritten as “being reasonable has to be a trait of one.”

Comment: While "of one" is possible, your particular sentence is very odd.  English doesn't use "one" very much in this sense and "a reasonable trait" is a very strange sounding expression.  The general oddity makes it very hard to comment.

Comment: However, generally,  if you know there is a correct way to express yourself, you need to explain why you want to express yourself differently.  Why would you say "being reasonable has to be a trait of one" when you could say "one has to have a reasonable trait"?

Comment: I struggle to think up an example of a natural sentence ending with pronoun "one" in the meaning of "anybody". The usage rules for that meaning of "one" are unique. I don't know what they are, but it's possible they preclude -- rather than expressly forbidding -- the usage of "one" at the end of a sentence. Like, maybe it can only be used as a subject. That would make it impossible to put at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Also, a "reasonable trait" means "a trait that is reasonable". It does not mean "the trait of being reasonable".

Comment: With a bit of a recast you could perhaps squeeze "oneself" in at the end, but I've no idea what to do with the 'reasonable trait' part. "As a trait, one could be reasonable oneself" feels a bit of a stretch.